# Failed to perform, ErrCode: 35, Reason: 'Recv failure: Connection was reset'. error while requesting to twitter

Tags: python, ssl, curl, python-requests

my code is

```
async def request_username(self):
    url = "https://twitter.com/i/api/1.1/account/settings.json"
    response, response_json = await self.request("POST", url)
    self.account.username = response_json["screen_name"]
```

when i run this code i get an error on my own PC:
`Failed to perform, ErrCode: 35, Reason: 'Recv failure: Connection was reset'. This may be a libcurl error, See https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html first for more details.`

on the orther PC i get different error:
`Failed to perform, ErrCode: 35, Reason: 'BoringSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to twitter.com:443 '. This may be a libcurl error, See https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html first for more details.`

same request in cmd

```
curl -v https://twitter.com/i/api/1.1/account/settings.json
```

- Trying 104.244.42.65:443...
- Connected to twitter.com (104.244.42.65) port 443
- schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
- ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
- Recv failure: Connection was reset
- schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
- Closing connection
- schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with twitter.com port 443
- Send failure: Connection was reset
- schannel: failed to send close msg: Failed sending data to the peer (bytes written: -1)
  curl: (35) Recv failure: Connection was reset

i've tried to install new certificates, so now i have 600 of them. i've also tried to install openSSL and upgrade curl to the latest version and nothing helps. also tried to disable SSL and many common solutions on google and nothing helps.